# How to bind an event in a Facebook Like Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, events, facebook-like

first of all, sorry for my bad english.
I would like to create a "like-close" button for my site. Now I'll explain what I mean.

I've created 2 div, 1 for an overlay background in all the browser window and one for a window where I ask users to "Like" my facebook page.
I have also created a close button for hide the 2 divs and in this button I have hidden another Facebook Like Button and, when a user try to close the popup, he will put a "Like". In this button I wrote "close and like" so, for who thinks It's a clickjacking, the users know what they are doing.

I've been able to close the window in the same moment when the user click on the button on the first time (so, before he didn't like my page) with the method

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
   jQuery('#overlay').hide(); //hide the overlay
   jQuery('#popoup').hide(); //hide the popup window
});
```

Now when he visit my page again, the popup will appear again and I don't know how to close it without "dislike" the page.
I tried to bind an event "click" in the iframe of like button but it didn't work.
I tried to bind an event in the wrapper of the iframe but it didn't work...

So I have no more ideas and I know it's possibile because I saw this trick in another web site.

Thank you all for help

Comment: _“and in this button I have hidden another Facebook Like Button and, when a user try to close the popup, he will put a "Like"”_ – Are you asking us how to implement clickjacking to get users to involuntarily like stuff?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, in the button where I hide the Facebook like I wrote "like and close". It's the only button in the Window for show the main page content just to fans.